# WSO2 ESB Clustering + load balancing

Tags: wso2

I created a WSO2 ESB Cluster using WSO2 ELB using the reference
http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26839403

Everything is fine. But i had a doubt in Load balancing. And tried the same in WSO2 AS.
I deployed a Sample JSP file with a sysout statement and deployed in the management console.

Now while hitting the jsp application, the sysout data is printed only on the management terminal console... There is no change in the other two worker node console...

Is clustering happened? if it is so, then how to find which worker node processed the request?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you haven't configure a Deployment Synchronizer among the nodes. It'll be through this mechanism a manager node can share artifacts among worker nodes. If it's not enabled, the JSP page you have uploaded will only reside in the node you have uploaded it to. You can find more details about the Deployment Synchronizer at http://docs.wso2.org/display/Cluster/Configuring+Deployment+Synchronizer

Comment: Is it the same for WSO2ESB clustering also? My primary target is to create WSO2ESB clustering and ensure that it is working properly.

Comment: Yes.This can be applied for ESB cluster.